# Format a date on Pdfmake

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, pdfmake

I have used **[pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake)** library to export pdf content with the **[Angular UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/206_exporting_data)**.Could you tell me how to format the date on it ? Thanks.

Currently it shows like this :

[image]

Angular grid it's like this :

[image]

```
 {
   name: app.localize('BrDateReceived'),
   field: 'bpoHeaderPerformedFors[0].dateReceived',
   cellFilter: 'date:\'MM/dd/yyyy\'',
   width: 140,
 },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Good discussion :** **[cellFilter does not work with the Pdfmake](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/5011)**

**UPDATE**

I discovered that UI-grid has a function in gridoptions that allows you to call back on each cell. Using angular-moment and the gridoptions.exporterFieldCallback I was able to change each cell in the PDF. Look at lines 43 to 47 in the app.js file in this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3L2TtwnJSkyIyifX0tWd?p=preview).

Also, note that I updated the link below to use angular-moment with the correct repo on github. The one I used earlier was not the one I would recommend.

Good luck!

**Original Answer**

I suggest importing angular-moment into your app, and then using it in your document definition. I have done this successfully before. Like this:

```
{text: 'DATE: ' + moment(bpoHeaderPerformedFors[0].dateReceived).format("MM-DD-YYYY")}
```

View more about [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) or full docs of [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) (which the angular version is based).

Good luck!

Comment: Can't we do this by using `momnetJs` only ? I mean without using angular version ?

Comment: Yes, I have done it successfully with nodejs backend no problem. You referenced angular in your question so that is why I suggested it, but if you are creating the pdf on the server momentjs would be the way to go.

Comment: But the problem here is it does not work with the `UI-Grid`.It is working fine only with the `Pdfmake`.But the problem I have is how can I find a solution for the  `UI-Grid` ? B'cos it does not detect the `momentjs` within the  `field:` property.

Comment: Unless you add angular-momentjs to your app it won't be able to call it. That said, I have never tried angular-momentjs with ui-grid so I don't know if it would work. How are you sending the data to pdfmake? I would suspect that the two (ui-grid and pdfmake) are different processes. Is that not correct?

Comment: Here you can see how it works with the `UI-Grid`. Actually it is an inbuilt feature of the `UI-Grid`. http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/206_exporting_data

Comment: Ok. Sorry, I didn't see that. First, did you download pdfmake from github or did you use npm or bower (as suggested in the ui-grid link)? I know that the NPM files were not in sync with github (it was older) so there were several features that did not work. Can you download pdfmake directly from [github](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake) first and then try it again using the UI-grid formatting?

Comment: Yes,I have tried like that.I have downloaded `Pdfmake` from the git.But no luck :(

Comment: Just updated answer with a working plnkr. Should solve the issue for you, but let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use a combination of the exporterFieldCallback function and angular built in filter. First include the $filter:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope,$filter){
```

And then in your gridoptions:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
exporterFieldCallback: function (grid, row, col, input)
    {
        if (col.name == 'myDateColumnName')
        {
            return $filter('date')(input, 'medium');
        } 
        else
        {
            return input;
        }
    },
}
```

You could use any date filter type you like, medium was just an example that fit for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same code as [phattyD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2355927/phattyd) says. I also ask for the default cell template that comes with ui-grid to perform this check generically:

```
// Format the DATE
// http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.exporter.api:GridOptions 

gridOptions.exporterFieldCallback = function ( grid, row, col, value ){
  if ( col.colDef.cellTemplate == 'ui-grid/date-cell' || col.colDef.type == 'date' ){
    value = $filter('date')(value, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  }
  return value;
}
```

I attach my complete code to workaround the same situation for **Excel** and **CSV**.

Hope it helps

Here is my [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SKpZssfwvjpBEbMOyq4S?p=preview).